# Vue how to test component with slot and slot-props

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, testing, frontend, vue-test-utils

I want to test this `FooComponent`:

```html
<div>
  <slot :fn="internalFn" />
</div>
```

It's used like that (e.g. in `ParentComponent`):

```html
<FooComponent>
  <template slot-scope="slotProps">
    <BarComponent @some-event="slotProps.fn" />
  </template>
</FooComponent>
```

So I want to test how my component reacts on calling this "fn" from slot props. The easiest way I see is to take method itself and call it, like that:

```js
cosnt wrapper = shallowMount(FooComponent, /* ... */)
wrapper.vm.methods.internalFn(/* test payload */)
expect(wrapper.emitted()).toBe(/* some expectation */)
```

But this is well known as anti-pattern about testing internal implementation. So instead I would like to test it via prop `fn` passed into slot, because it's also some sort of component interface, like component own props.

But how to to test props passed in slot? I can imagine it's working only in case if I test that `ParentComponent` something like that:

```js
const wrapper = shallowMount(ParentComponent, /* ... */)
const foo = wrapper.find(FooComponent)
wrapper.find(BarComponent).vm.$emit('some-event', /*...*/)
/* write expectations against foo */
```

But that feels like tests for `FooComponent` inside tests for `ParentComponent`

Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:** below the line is the original answer that I gave years ago. For today I would say that one of these approaches would be good enough:

1. Don't test the slot method, but test the user-facing feature that relies on it. Try to test it manually first, notice how do you do it, then try to write a similar test. E.g. with [testing-library/vue](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro/)
2. If the first option is too hard to do, try to come up with some fake testing component. The idea is very similar to what I described in the question

> But that feels like tests for FooComponent inside tests for ParentComponent

But instead of using the `ParentComponent` just create some very simple inline component (right in your `FooComponent.spec.js` file), that uses the component with a slot.

---

*Original answer that was given in 2020:*

Since there are no answers so I just share what I ended up with.

I decided to test the internal method. It's not cool, but at least, because I use typescript, I have a type-safe test, which will fail with a clear type error if I rename or modify the method which I test. Looks like this:

```js
import Foo from '@/components/foo/Foo.ts'
import FooComponent from '@/components/foo/Foo.vue'

/*...*/

cosnt wrapper = <Foo>shallowMount(FooComponent, /* ... */)

// notice that because I passed `Foo` which is a class-component, 
// I have autocomplete and type checks for vm.*
wrapper.vm.internalFn(/* test payload */)

expect(wrapper.emitted()).toBe(/* some expectation */)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party but I just hit the same problem. I took a few cues from the actual Vue tests themselves, while they're more abstract in what they're testing compared to us, it did help.

Here's what I came up with:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Component from 'xyz/Component';

let wrapperSlotted;

describe('xyz/Component.vue', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    wrapperSlotted = shallowMount(Component, {
      data() {
        return { myProp: 'small' }
      },
      scopedSlots: {
        default: function (props) {
          return this.$createElement('div', [props.myProp]);
        }
      },
    });
  });

  it('slot prop passed to a scoped slot', () => {
    let text = wrapperSlotted.find('div').text();
    expect(text).toBe('small'); // the value of `myProp`, which has been set as the text node in the slotted <div />
  });
});
```

So the main thing was that I used the render function for `scopedSlots`.

Hope that helps someone :)

Comment: A principle of tests is that a test should not break if the functionality it tests
does not change. Using a toBe matcher to check all rendered text of a component violates this principle. A toBe matcher would check that all the text in a component strictly equals the expected value. If you decided to change small to tiny, for example, the test would break.